# How to reuse a router pipeline definiton in another pipeline definition in phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to define two pipelines in my `web/router.ex` file as follows:

```
pipeline :api do
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
  plug :fetch_session
  plug MyApp.Plugs.ValidatePayload
end

pipeline :restricted_api do
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
  plug :fetch_session
  plug MyApp.Plugs.ValidatePayload
  plug MyApp.Plugs.EnsureAuthenticated
  plug MyApp.Plugs.EnsureAuthorized
end
```

You can clearly see that steps from the `:api` pipeline are duplicated in the `:restricted_api` pipeline.

**Is there a way to reuse the `:api` pipeline in the `:restricted_api` pipeline?**

I am thinking about something similar to inheritance:

```
pipeline :api do
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
  plug :fetch_session
  plug MyApp.Plugs.ValidatePayload
end

pipeline :restricted_api do
  extend :api
  plug MyApp.Plugs.EnsureAuthenticated
  plug MyApp.Plugs.EnsureAuthorized
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `pipeline` macro creates a function plug. Therefore it can be used in other pipelines like any other plug with `plug :pipeline`. In the provided example:

```
pipeline :api do
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
  plug :fetch_session
  plug MyApp.Plugs.ValidatePayload
end

pipeline :restricted_api do
  plug :api
  plug MyApp.Plugs.EnsureAuthenticated
  plug MyApp.Plugs.EnsureAuthorized
end
```